# Linear discriminant scores using caret

Tags: r, caret, discriminant-analysis

I'm using the caret package in R to undertake an LDA. I'm having problems trying to extract the linear discriminant scores once I've used predict.

The model is ...

```
ldaFit1 <- train(x=training[,predictor.vars],y=training$GroupID,method="lda2",trControl = ctrl1,preProc=c("center","scale"), parms=list(priors = prior))
```

and I use the standard prediction call to get the predicted classes

```
testing.lda <- predict(ldaFit1,testing)
```

or to get the posterior probabilities ..

```
testing.lda <- predict(ldaFit1,testing,type="prob")
```

What I can't seem to find is how to get the actual LDA scores. If I undertake LDA using the standard MASS package the scores would be contained in the predicted object and accessed via object$x.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?